# Emacs theme looks weird with MobaXterm

Tags: emacs

I am using MobaXterm with default settings and Emacs 25 with no forwarding window.

```
emacs --nw
```

MobaXterm has basic highlights in the shell, but it seems that it interferes with Emacs themes. When I load the `spacemacs-dark` theme in Emacs, it doesn't show. When I load the `cherry-blossom` theme, it is pink all over the place.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the answer at [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorThemeQuestions). Put this in the .bashrc file:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

This is not a MobaXterm specific questions.

Comment: I had been dabbling with MobeXterm's colour schemes for quite some time. This was extremely helpful!